# Splitting a SQL table row into php variables

Tags: php, sql, variables, explode

I have a row in my table which displays as such;

```
2:2/3:1/17:1/6:1/1:1/
```

I am wondering how I could store those into php variables so I can display them to the user. The '/' seperates the elements and the ':' seperates the parts of the element.

I don't know if that makes sense, but it's like this;

```
itemID:quantity/itemID:quantity/itemID:quantity/
```

So I want to seperate the items and then store the itemID and the quantity into variables to dislay to the user.

I have tried using the explode function;

```
$pieces = explode("/", $order_details);
```

But I don't know how to seperate the itemID and the quantity.

Any help?

Comment: If you normalize your database you won't have issues like this

Comment: I think you can repeat the explode on each piece, using explode(":", piece.  However, it would seem that you database structure should have a separate row for each item and quantity, rather then combining them all into a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pieces = explode("/", rtrim($order_details, '/'));
$items = array();
foreach ($pieces as $piece)
{
    list($id, $qty) = explode(':', $piece);
    $items[$id] = $qty;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How would I go about setting it up so that the id = $id and the quanity = $qty?

Comment: Just remove the second line of the foreach loop.

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly. One more thing, is there anyway it can ignore the last '/' that is on the end of the string? I'm getting an error because it is looking for the ':' in the last item but there isn't one.

Comment: Just strip it off either using `substr()` or `rtrim()`. See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: You're a true gent, mate. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
<?php
$str = '2:2/3:1/17:1/6:1/1:1/';
$str = str_replace(array(':', '/'), array('=', '&'), $str);

parse_str($str, $vars);

/*
$vars now:
Array
(
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 1
    [17] => 1
    [6] => 1
    [1] => 1
)
*/
```

If possible, store the value to your table as [serialized array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).